# Chronological Sentiment Analysis -- Cannot group by lines

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

My data *text* is a novel in plain text. I used packages tm and tidytext. Data processing went well and I created my DocumentTermMatrix without trouble.

```
text <- read_lines("GoneWithTheWind2.txt")
set.seed(314) 
text <- iconv(text,'UTF-8',sub="")
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"), 
stopwords("SMART"), mystopwords, Top200Words))  
myDtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control=list(minWordLength= 1))`
```

However, I could not run the coding using *inner_join* between bing lexicon and the DocumentTermMatrix to do chronological sentiment analysis of this novel over time. I wrote the function below based on an online example but did not know what to group by in count(sentiment) (I place ???? in hold), because the plain text and the DocumentTermMatrix has no "lines" columns.

```
bing <- get_sentiments("bing")  
m <- as.matrix(myDtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
myNames <- names(v)
d <- data.frame(term=myNames, freq = v)
wind_polarity <- d %>%
# Inner join to the lexicon
inner_join(bing, by=c("term"="word")) %>%
# Count by sentiment, **????**
count(sentiment, **????**) %>%
# Spread sentiments
spread(sentiment, n, fill=0) %>%
mutate(
# Add polarity field
polarity = positive - negative,
# Add line number field
line_number = row_number())
Then plot by ggplot.
```

I tried adding a column "Index" indicating the line number for each document (line) in *text* but this column disappears somewhere in the process. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have not mentioned the packages you are using. Please, [edit] your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post your desired ouput in combination with a reproducible example. You might use the following short example `text <- c("I like coffee", "I rather like tea", "I hate coffee and tea but I love orange juice")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an approach that calculates the polarity per line (based on a minimum example of three lines). You might join your dtm with the lexicon directly to maintain information on the counts. Then turn polarity information into numeric representation and do your calculations per line. You might certainly rewrite the code and make it more elegant (I am not very familiar with dplyr vocabulary, sorry). I hope that helps anyway.

```
library(tm)
library(tidytext)

text <- c("I like coffe."
          ,"I rather like tea."
          ,"I hate coffee and tea, but I love orange juice.")

myDtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(VCorpus(VectorSource(text)),
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE))

bing <- tidytext::get_sentiments("bing")  

wind_polarity <- as.matrix(myDtm) %>%
  data.frame(terms = rownames(myDtm), ., stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  inner_join(bing, by= c("terms"="word")) %>%
  mutate(terms = NULL,
         polarity = ifelse( (.[,"sentiment"] == "positive"), 1,-1),
         sentiment = NULL) %>%
  { . * .$polarity } %>% 
  mutate(polarity = NULL) %>% 
  colSums

#the polarity per line which you may plot, e.g., with base or ggplot
# X1 X2 X3 
# 1  1  0
```

Comment: I am glad the solution works for you. Good luck with your project.